# convert and print a command output string to hash object

Tags: ruby, hash

i have a output of command stored in a string variable.
i am trying to convert this into a hash object in ruby script.

Here is the command output:

```
#lldptool get-tlv -n -i p2p1
Chassis ID TLV
            MAC: 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    Port ID TLV
            Ifname: Ethernet1/3

    System Capabilities TLV
            System capabilities:  Bridge, Router
            Enabled capabilities: Bridge
```

so i want the final result to be of this format with {key:value} pairs.

```
{"Chassis ID TLV”=>"00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", "Port ID TLV”=>“Ethernet1/3”, "System Capabilities TLV"=>{"System capabilities"=>"Bridge, Router", "Enabled capabilities"=>"Bridge"} }
```

Here is what i tried

```
lldp_hash = {
    # LLDP Name    Numeric value
    'chassisID'    => '1',
    'portID'       => '2',
    'System Capabilities TLV' => '3'
  }

x = `lldptool get-tlv -n -i p2p1  2>/dev/null`
x = x.split("\n")
puts x
```

I am not figuring a way to assign the keys to the values present in the string with which i can print the above desired format of hash.
can someone provide some help over here.

Comment: I'd suggest your best option is create a parser - Have a look at http://www.blackbytes.info/2015/04/parsing-with-ruby/

Comment: The line you show after "so i want the final result to be of this format with {key:value} pairs." is not valid Ruby, nor is it valid JSON or YAML. It is, in fact, not valid code or data in any language I know.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry. my bad. i updated it.

Comment: Before you try to write your own parser for this, there are a number of LLDP libraries out there for Ruby. One of them probably does what you need. I can't recommend any of them particularly.